# Trying to import and use HTML from Drei but keep getting error

Tags: react-three-fiber

```
  import { Html } from '@react-three/drei';
   
 ./node_modules/three-stdlib/lights/RectAreaLightUniformsLib.js
    Attempted import error: 'DataUtils' is not exported from 'three'.
```

Ive tried looking at the documentation on drei for HTML
What I got still doesn't work

```
The native route of the library does not export Html or Loader. The default export of the library is web which does export Html and Loader.
import { Icosahedron, Html, OrthographicCamera } from '../../src'



import { HtmlProps, CalculatePosition } from 'web/Html'
```

When I use

```
import { Html, useProgress, useGLTFLoader } from "drei";
```

It works

but when I use

```
  import { Html } from '@react-three/drei';
```

It breaks

Comment: drei is inherently linked to threejs, make sure versions at least match or everything is at latest. three does not use semver that makes it quite hard, but drei will always work with latest three. "drei" is deprecated, always use @react-three/...

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and solved it with `npm install three-stdlib`. I found the hint at the top of the README for the drei git repo: https://github.com/pmndrs/drei

> A growing collection of useful helpers and abstractions for react-three-fiber.
>
> `npm install @react-three/drei`
>
> this package is using the stand-alone [three-stdlib](https://github.com/pmndrs/three-stdlib) instead of [three/examples/jsm](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/jsm)